# WPF UserControl Animation in Code-behind Not Working with ContentPresenter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

When the code is like this, the animation **works** as expected.

**AnimatedUserControl2.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfPoc20120908.AnimatedUserControl2"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" IsVisibleChanged="AnimatedUserControl2_OnIsVisibleChanged">
    <Grid Background="Coral">
        <Canvas>
            <TextBlock x:Name="MNB" Text="ABCD"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**AnimatedUserControl2.xaml.cs** (Partial Code Only)

```
        private void AnimatedUserControl2_OnIsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
            {
                var storyboard = new Storyboard();
                var visibilityAnimation = new ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
                visibilityAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame(Visibility.Visible,
                                                                             KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0))));
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(visibilityAnimation, new PropertyPath(VisibilityProperty));
                storyboard.Children.Add(visibilityAnimation);
                var opacityAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(0, 1, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(opacityAnimation, new PropertyPath(OpacityProperty));
                storyboard.Children.Add(opacityAnimation);
                var canvasLeftAnimation = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
                canvasLeftAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(new LinearDoubleKeyFrame(200,
                                                                           KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0))));
                canvasLeftAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(new SplineDoubleKeyFrame(0, KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)),
                                                                           new KeySpline(new Point(0.25, 0.1),
                                                                                         new Point(0.25, 1))));
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(canvasLeftAnimation, new PropertyPath(Canvas.LeftProperty));
                storyboard.Children.Add(canvasLeftAnimation);
                MNB.BeginStoryboard(storyboard, HandoffBehavior.SnapshotAndReplace, false);
            }
        }
```

However, when I use a ContentPresenter in the XAML code, the animation **does not work at all**.

**AnimationUserControl2.xaml** (1st Revision)

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfPoc20120908.AnimatedUserControl2"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" IsVisibleChanged="AnimatedUserControl2_OnIsVisibleChanged">
    <Grid Background="Coral">
        <Canvas>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="MNB"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

When I try to wrap the ContentPresenter with a Grid, the animation **still doesn't work**.

**AnimationUserControl2.xaml** (2nd Revision)

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfPoc20120908.AnimatedUserControl2"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" IsVisibleChanged="AnimatedUserControl2_OnIsVisibleChanged">
    <Grid Background="Coral">
        <Canvas>
            <Grid x:Name="MNB">
                <ContentPresenter/>
            </Grid>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here's the question. **How can I get the animation to work with a ContentPresenter?**

**UPDATE 01**

Here's how AnimatedUserControl2 is used.

**MainWindow.xaml** (Partial Code Only)

```
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical">
            <usercontrols:AnimatedUserControl2 x:Name="ABCD" Visibility="Hidden">
                <TextBlock Text="ABC"/>
            </usercontrols:AnimatedUserControl2>
            <usercontrols:AnimatedUserControl2 x:Name="EFGH" Visibility="Hidden" Margin="10">
                <TextBlock Text="ABC"/>
            </usercontrols:AnimatedUserControl2>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="ButtonBeginAnimation" Click="ButtonBeginAnimation_OnClick" Content="Begin Animation" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs** (Partial Code Only)

```
        private void ButtonBeginAnimation_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ABCD.Visibility = (ABCD.Visibility == Visibility.Visible) ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
            EFGH.Visibility = (EFGH.Visibility == Visibility.Visible) ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
        }
```

Comment: You are using UserControl with content presenter in it, which seems weird.. How do you put your content to the UserControl? Can you show some xam code where AnimatedUserControl2 is actually used?

Comment: Hi, @SebastianÐymel. I have updated the question with more details. Basically, I specify the content in XAML code. This is similar to how I specify the content of panel controls (e.g. Grid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is with how you're using your user control - you simply override content once specified inside UserControl xaml definition... anyway..
Try this approach (animation works on my machine so suppose to work on yours as well ;))

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication11.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         d:DesignHeight="300"
         d:DesignWidth="300"
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<UserControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
        <Grid Background="Coral">
            <Canvas>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="MNB" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Template>
```

And in animation itself:

```
  private void AnimatedUserControl2_OnIsVisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var mnb = Template.FindName("MNB", this) as FrameworkElement;
        if (mnb == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
        {
            var storyboard = new Storyboard();
            var visibilityAnimation = new ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
            visibilityAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame(Visibility.Visible,
                                                                         KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0))));
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(visibilityAnimation, new PropertyPath(VisibilityProperty));
            storyboard.Children.Add(visibilityAnimation);
            var opacityAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(0, 1, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(opacityAnimation, new PropertyPath(OpacityProperty));
            storyboard.Children.Add(opacityAnimation);
            var canvasLeftAnimation = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
            canvasLeftAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(new LinearDoubleKeyFrame(200,
                                                                       KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0))));
            canvasLeftAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(new SplineDoubleKeyFrame(0, KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)),
                                                                       new KeySpline(new Point(0.25, 0.1),
                                                                                     new Point(0.25, 1))));
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(canvasLeftAnimation, new PropertyPath(Canvas.LeftProperty));
            storyboard.Children.Add(canvasLeftAnimation);
            mnb.BeginStoryboard(storyboard, HandoffBehavior.SnapshotAndReplace, false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, @SebastianÐymel.  I got an exception when I tried to use your code. It turns out that your method signature did not match the expected method signature. To fix this, I changed the parameters from `(object sender, EventArgs e)` to `(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)`. It worked after that. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Hi, @SebastianÐymel. I edited your answer a bit because of the exception I got.